# Android RecyclerView - very long images not showing / blacked out while still using the space

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-xml

This is the image inside RecyclerView item:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/PicContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/MemeImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/picLoadIcon"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

When the image is like 2 times longer than the height of the display then the image isn't showing, it's blacked out while still using the space.

This is how I load them:

```
        holder.picContainer.layoutParams.height = endHeightImage

        holder.image.setMarginExtensionFunction(0, 0, 0, -cutOff)

        Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(fileUrl)
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Drawable?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    holder.picLoadIcon.visibility = View.GONE
                    return false
                }
            })
            .apply(glideOptions)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(holder.image)
```

The nagative margin is for hiding the bottom watermark, in case it matters.

Comment: also try to add  .placeholder(R.drawable.PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_NAME)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try setting the ImageView's Height to wrap content instead of Matching the Relative Layout.

```
  <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/MemeImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" .../>
```